# Amazon SQS : Maximum messages can be deleted in single request

Tags: amazon-sqs

How many messages can be deleted in a single request from Amazon SQS?

I went through the documentation but couldn't find the limit figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to delete messages from SQS queue.

1. Delete messages one by one - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html
2. Delete messages in batch - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessageBatch.html

And the documentation of DeleteMessageBatch says this -

> Deletes up to ten messages from the specified queue.

So, its maximum **10** messages that you can delete form the queue.